# How to generate java's hashcode method in intellij with its members sorted?

Tags: java, eclipse, sorting, intellij-idea, hashcode

I want to generate the the java equals() and hashcode() method in Intellij. I want it to generate the way how eclipse generates. I have created a custom template to do this. But, in the hashcode method generated by intellij, the members are in the order they are listed, not alphabetically. But eclipse sorts them alphabetically when generating equals and hashcode method. I need to achieve this in Intellij. I couldn't find any sort function to use. Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: If you need this, then raise a bug report in IntelliJ.

Comment: I'm really curious why you want to force that?

Comment: In my project team, some people use eclipse and most of the code is written using eclipse's features. I joined the team recently and so I've to follow what is followed till now right? I'm accustomed to Intellij. So, if there is any way to do this? Do you think it is possible to write a sorting algorithm (bubble sort or any sort) to achieve this?

Comment: I found this [sorttool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/SortTool.html). Is it possible to use this in Intellij Velocity Templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @CrazyCoder's [suggestion](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Sort-List-of-Objects-in-Velocity/qaq-p/539823), I developed a macro for intellij.

```
#macro(sort $array)
  #set($size=$array.size())
  #set($index1=0)
  #foreach($element1 in $array)
    #set($index2=0)
    #set($minElement=$element1)
    #set($minElementIndex=$index1)
    #foreach($element2 in $array)
      #if($index2>$index1)
        #if($minElement.name.compareTo($element2.name)>0)
          #set($minElement=$element2)
          #set($minElementIndex=$index2)
        #end
      #end
      #set($index2=$index2+1)
    #end
    #set($temp=$array.get($index1))
    #set($junk=$array.set($index1, $minElement))
    #set($junk=$array.set($minElementIndex, $temp))
    #set($index1=$index1+1)
  #end
#end
```

Works good.

Answer (score 3):

This request was already submitted for IntelliJ IDEA and it was [declined with the following comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85447#comment=27-326141):

> We assume that you have ordered your members in a meaningful order
>   within the file, and that preserving this order would be more
>   meaningful than alphabetic sorting.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think it is possible to write a sorting algorithm (bubble sort or any sort) to achieve this?

Comment: @NagabhushanSN templates are based on Velocity language and it should be possible to implement sorting, [here is an example](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Sort-List-of-Objects-in-Velocity/qaq-p/539823).

Comment: thank you for the example. I'll look into it. I found this [sorttool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/SortTool.html).
Is it possible to use this in Intellij Velocity Templates?